# Visual Studio project based coloring

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros

We have dev qa and prod environments each with its own source control branch.  Is there any add ons or macros that could change the Visual Studio window in some noticeable way based upon some type of information in the solution or project file.

I thought of this because when I was a unix system admin and I logged in as root my console font color would change so that at a glance I could tell I was root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) addin for VS2010. In particular, the `Tab UI` feature in the description:

> Color tabs according to their project
>   or according to regular expressions.
>   This option permits tabs to be colored
>   according to the project they belong
>   to.This is particularly useful when
>   sorting tabs by project, as it allows
>   you to immediately identify different
>   groups of project documents.
>       You can also configure regular expressions and assign a color to each
>   one. If the name of a tab matches the
>   configured regular expression, it will
>   be colored with the assigned color.